# TFS Build with PostSharp Debug | Any CPU

Tags: tfs, build, postsharp

I have a .Net project (framework 4.0) that references PostSharp assembly (version 2.1). The project is configured for Debug and Release with Any CPU.

I'm trying to build that project on TFS (2012), created a build definition where I add two workspaces:
- One workspace with the directory where is the PostSharp.dll assembly
- One workspace where the .csproj file is.

The configuration I added is **Debug | Any CPU**.
When I attempt to build, it states that everything works fine but warns that my project doesn't have an OutputPath configured. After googling, I found out that it was related with the Any CPU, that should be AnyCPU without the space.

But if I do this, when TFS attempts to build my project it states that The type or namespace name "PostSharp" could not be found.

So if I use **Any CPU** TFS seems to recognize PostSharp, but if I use **AnyCPU** seems to recognize my project but not PostSharp.

Is there any workaround for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I found the answer, it was the Build agent folder for my PostSharp assembly directory that was wrong. Works fine now.